# PHP update database with data-value from a form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am building a wordpress plugin that displays a form on a page. In the form is a dynamically populated drop down list of singers (singers is a custom post type where the admin enters the singer name and singer gender - stored as variables in wp_postmeta "singer_name" and "singer_gender").

In the form, I have added the singer gender as a data variable in the option, for example:

```
<select name="about_performance_lead_singer" id="about_performance_lead_singer" value="">

<option disabled="" selected=""> -- Choose a singer -- </option>
<option data-gender="female" value="Toni">Toni</option>
<option data-gender="male" value="Jack">Jack</option>
<option data-gender="male" value="James">James</option>        

</select>
```

This code is generated using the following php:

```
$singers = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'  => 'singers',
        'numberposts' => -1
    )
    );
    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $singers as $singer ) {
        echo "<option data-gender='".esc_html( $singer->singer_gender )."' value='".esc_html( $singer->singer_name )."' >" . esc_html( $singer->singer_name ) . "</option>"; 
    }
```

When the form is submitted, I want to update a row in the wp_postmeta table called "wedding_singer_gender" - this row is specific to the booking form being filled out. Here is how I update the specific row, I don't know how to fill it with the 'data-gender' variable

```
// Get booking form ID from URL query string
$booking_form_id = get_query_var( 'booking-id' );

update_post_meta($booking_form_id, 'wedding_singer_gender', *WEDDING SINGER GENDER*);
```

Comment: Why not just get the singers again when the form is submitted and find the gender that way? Also, the singers don't have a specific id, so you could possibly have multiple singers with the same name.

Comment: @RyanWillis since "singers" is a custom post type, they do have a unique id - would you suggest me adding this as another data variable i.e. data-singer-id? Or perhaps I should change the value to the ID?

Comment: Yes, the value of a select box should always be unique. Rakib's answer is solid

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way to handle this is......
1. On form submission store the $singer_id to wp_postmeta with $booking_id

```
<select name="about_performance_lead_singer" id="about_performance_lead_singer" value="">

<option disabled="" selected=""> -- Choose a singer -- </option>
<option  value="1">Toni</option>
<option  value="2">Jack</option>
<option value="3">James</option>        
</select>
```

where 1,2,3 etc will be $artist_id 
generate with this code

```
$singers = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'  => 'singers',
        'numberposts' => -1
    )
    );
    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $singers as $singer ) {
        echo "<option  value='".esc_html( $singer->ID )."' >" . esc_html( $singer->singer_name ) . "</option>"; 
    }
```

When you need to retrieve artist details.
1. Get the artist/ singer Id from post meta using 
`get_post_meta ($booking_id, 'singer_id')`
2. Get singer details using the singer id 
`get_post_meta ($singer_id, 'singer_gender')`

hope this will help.